# What creature is Filli in Deltora Quest?

Tags: deltora-quest

In The Deltora Quest Anime, Jasmine is occupied by some type of animal creature, which almost resembles a little furry fuzzball, but what creature is Filli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Deltora Quest Wiki:](http://deltoraquest.wikia.com/wiki/Filli)

> Filli is a Siskis and one of Jasmine's animal companions, along with
>   Kree.

To know more about this ["Siskis"](http://deltoraquest.wikia.com/wiki/Siskis) species:

> Siskis were described by Doran in his journal, during his travels. The
>   journal was later published as Secrets of Deltora by King Lief. In the
>   book he described them as bright-eyed, highly intelligent creatures
>   found in Mid Wood, in Topaz territory. However, he also wrote that the
>   species were going extinct.